# Are there any states which never had any appointed Senators?

Tags: united-states, senate, political-appointments

In most states, the governor is able to appoint Senators on a temporary basis.

Senator Jon Kyl's appointment [was the first in Arizona](https://www.azcentral.com/story/news/politics/arizona/2017/07/20/what-if-senator-mccain-leaves-office-how-process-works/494621001/). Are there any states where no Senators have ever been appointed?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, according to the [Senate Historical Office's list of appointed Senators since 1913](https://www.senate.gov/senators/AppointedSenators.htm)<sup>1</sup>. The following three states never had any appointed Senators since 1913:

- Maryland
- Utah
- Wisconsin

1913 is the year in which the [Seventeenth Amendment to the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventeenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) Constitution was ratified. It established means of filling vacant Senate seats and the direct election of senators.

Furthermore, the following state legislatures *currently* do not empower the governor to appoint Senators:

- North Dakota
- Oklahoma
- Oregon
- Rhode Island
- Wisconsin

North Dakota, Oklahoma, Oregon and Rhode Island had appointed Senators before the respective state legislatures changed their laws and prevented the governors from appointing Senators on a temporary basis.

So, there won't be any appointed Senators from Wisconsin for some time.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Senate Historical Office does not keep records of appointed Senators before 1913. See https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/R44781.pdf, page 13, "Senate Historical Office maintains records for Senators appointed since 1913"

Comment: What process do those states have for filing vacancies then? Seems kind of odd that a state would vote to reduce its own suffrage in the Senate if one of their own leaves office for whatever reason.

Comment: @WesSayeed Those 5 states are a subset of the 14 states in which a special election is held to fill the vacancy. The position remains vacant in those 5 until the special election, typically in 30-90 days. For the other 9 states, the governor appoints a temporary senator until the special election. See [this list](http://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/vacancies-in-the-united-states-senate.aspx). The idea is the senator is only selected through vote, never by appointment.